# Laravel problema con paginación

Tags: laravel, paginación

Tengo una lectura paginada de un modelo `Category`, así:

```
$categorias = Category::orderBy('cat_name')
    ->paginate(10);
```

Esto realmente no devuelve una colección, como si fuera una consulta "normal", si no que la colección llega, a su vez, encerrada en una envolvente de la clase `LengthAwarePaginator`. Para usarla en la vista, no hay problema y, gracias a esa envolvente, en la vista se puede poner el método `links()` para pasar de una página a otra. Hasta aquí, bien.

El problema es cuando, una vez obtenida la colección, necesitamos modificar sus elementos. Por ejemplo, para las categorías tengo que leer los productos de cada una, lo que hago así:

```
$categorias = Category::orderBy('cat_name')
    ->paginate(10);

$categorias = $categorias->map(function ($category) {
    $category->productos = $category->products;
    return $category;
});
```

Por supuesto, el método `products()` existe en el modelo, define una relación y funciona perfectamente. Eso ya lo he comprobado.

Y aquí aparece el problema. Al usar el método `map()`, lo que obtengo, finalmente, en una colección, pura y dura, no envuelta en `LengthAwarePaginator`, por lo que, al intentar usar el método `links()` en la vista, da un error, porque ese método pertenece a `LengthAwarePaginator`, no a `Collection`.

He intentado volver a meter la colección en la envolvente adecuada, así:

```
$categorias = new LengthAwarePaginator($categorias, Category::count(), '10');
```

El caso es que la primera página del listado la muestra bien, y también los enlaces de paginación. Pero cuando pulso un enlace, aunque en la URL aparece el parámetro `page=2`, o `page=3`, o el que pulse, la vista no muestra los contenidos.

Cual es el problema? Como puedo lograr una paginación de datos que deben ser modificados antes de enviarse a la vista?

=============================================================================

No sé si este es el sitio para añadir contenido, pero como respuesta al comentario de Shaz, lo de EagerLoading no he tenido tiempo de experimentar con ello. Sin embargo, encontré una solución bastante cómoda viendo la firma del constructor de `LengthAwarePaginator`. Primero hago la lectura paginada inicial:

```
$categorias = Category::orderBy('cat_name')
        ->paginate(10);
```

Inmediatamente después, recupero una matriz de opciones de la paginación, que ví mirando docu:

```
$opciones = $categorias->getOptions();
```

Ahora ya puedo manipular la colección como necesite. No importa que me la saque de la envolvente de paginación. Cuando termino de manipularla, la vuelvo a meter, así:

```
$categorias = new LengthAwarePaginator($categorias, Category::count(), 10, null, $opciones);
```

Lo que daba el fallo era la falta del último parámetro, la matriz de `$opciones`. Poniéndola, funciona todo bien. Aún así, este finde me miraré a fondo lo del `EagerLoading`, por si optimiza el resultado.

Comment: ¿Por qué no utilizar Eager Loading para cargar los productos al momento de hacer la consulta?

Comment: No había oido de esto (cuanto más aprendes, más falta por aprender, a veces). Parece ser como un addon, que haya que añadir aparte, como si no fuera parte de Laravel por defecto ¿es así? Y una pregunta. ¿Realmente aporta soluciones más limpias de implementar para las consultas, las paginaciones, las actualizaciones de BD, etc?

Comment: Eager Loading viene incluido con Eloquent (Laravel). https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: ¿Qué pasó con esta pregunta?

Comment: He respondido editando la misma pregunta. No sé si se ajusta a las normas de este sitio, pero en comentarios no me cabía.